# Laravel allows only one time to submit one day

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a problem that I have not known since yesterday, I have searched on google still not found, hope someone knows the cause of this problem

I made a form like this:

```html
<form action="{{ route('file') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                            <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>address</label>
                            <textarea type="text" name="address" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>date</label>
                            <input type="text" name="date" class="date form-control"></input>
                            <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

My problem is, when someone submits, someone can re-submit, which I want when someone submits he cannot submit it again until a certain time limit, for example 2 hours.but other people who have not submitted can still submit (this is like a google form questionnaire , and people no need to login)

please help me if you can solve this problem, thank you very much

Comment: You need to log somewhere the last time a person submit the form. Then block the submit for that user until the time passed.

Comment: what should I block, if it's his name or cellphone number, what if he enters other data that makes the name and cellphone number unblocked

Comment: Does your user need to be logged in? If yes -> Then block is ID or Token or Whatever you use to identify your user. If no -> Then you are a bit screw... You can use a cookie, but the guest can delete it on client side. You can use a token into session, but it'll eventually be deleted.

Comment: Create another table, where you save the client user id (if authenticated user), or save their IP. when they tray to send you message again. Then check with the id or ip from your table.  I made the same for my personal blog's contact form to prevent spamming

Comment: not logged in, if I use login it will complicate the questionnaire even though it makes it safe, so I have to make a session ?? do you have any references to make it? , btw thanks for the fast response

Comment: @sta can we collect user ip when submit? How to? I just found out about that method

Comment: The simplest way to get the visitor’s/client’s IP address is using the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` variables

Comment: wow i already visited it was very good ,thanks btw, I just tried, and I can display the ip address, to give pause to the ip address so it doesn't resubmit, how do you do it? @sta

Comment: When you submit this form, you need to save the ip in your database.  And Every time, when you access this page, from controller you need to check clent IP with your database table. If the ip match with database and send you message within last 24 hours, then you can block this and throw an error message or send to another page

Comment: okay thanks a lot, I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to do any database work, but this is more dependent on your case.

However, to answer your question straight-forward, you could add the `Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests` on your `file` route.

Throttling is done at IP level, so I think it's exactly what you need: https://monosnap.com/file/PXayGqUwDI5C3kGwiwgFEFodT70nJd

```php
// route is accessible from IP once every 120 seconds

Route::post('file')->name('file')->middleware('throttle:1,120');
```

By doing this, when the same IP tries to access the route again in those 120 seconds, he'll get a `ThrottleRequestsException` exception (which you can handle in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class)

---

You can find the `throttle` middleware defined in your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file.

Here's the documentation for it: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting